# Photo printing woocommerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, image-uploading

I am in the process of scoping a website for a printing shop. I am going to use the Fancy Product Designer plugin for Woocommerce for the majority of what they sell but I need to find a plugin where by users can upload photos in bulk and then pay to have them printed. Does anyone know of such plugin?

Comment: Did you find anything? I'm also looking for such a plugin

Comment: Hi Martin - we ended up building our own bespoke solution. We couldn't find anything that really worked for what we needed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this plugin will help you to achieve the goal.But as per my understanding, you need to customize few things in it.
Plugin name: 'WooCommerce Upload Files '
Plugin Url: https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-upload-files/